# C Program doesn't continue to follow code in main() function after calling a function inside of it

Tags: c, function, program-entry-point

Won't execute the following code in the main() function. Any input is appreciated. P.S. I was in the beginning stages of creating a tic-tac-toe-game.

```
void printBoard(int slotNumber);

int main()
{
int slotNumberMain = -1;
printf("prints this\n");
printBoard(slotNumberMain);
printf("but not this\n");


return 0;
}

void printBoard(int slotNumber)
{

int boardSlots[3][3];
int i;
int j = 0;

for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++){
    char box[4] = {'[', ' ', ']', '\0'};
    boardSlots[j][i - 1] = i;

    if (slotNumber == i){
        char box[4] = {'[', 'X', ']', '\0'};
    }

    printf("%s", box);
    if (i % 3 == 0){
        j++;
        printf("\n");
        }
    }

}
```

Edit: The reason there is a slotNumber variable is because originally I had added a enterNumber() function (which would be called at the end of printBoard() and have had you enter a number and mark the box with an 'x' after recalling printBoard(slotNumberMain)) however I haven't added the code here, because I realized that the problem was strictly within printBoard() and main.)

Edit 2: I have solved the issue, it was due to the boardSlots array being overrun like someone had suggested.

Thanks to everyone who attempted to help.

Comment: Think about whether `i - 1` ever increases past 2. Also, a debugger helps in these situations and more, so you should find one for your platform.

Comment: After you overrun the `boardSlots` array, everything else is undefined behavior.  One strong possibility is that it overwrites the return address on the stack, so that the function returns somewhere else instead.

Comment: As a side note, the `if(slotNumber == i)` block will not do what you want; the `char box[]` declared inside that block is local to that block, and is separate from and will not affect  the `box` array declared in the outer block.  Your program will never print the X.

Comment: please check edit, thank you.

Comment: You have two variables called `box` whose lifetimes overlap. That's not good practice.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue, it was due to the boardSlots array being overrun like someone had suggested.

```
void printBoard(int slotNumber)
{

    int boardSlots[3][3];

    int i;
    int j = 1;
    char box[4] = {'[', ' ', ']', '\0'};

    for (i = 1; i <= 3 && j <= 3; i++){

        boardSlots[j - 1][i - 1] = i * j;

        if (slotNumber == i){
            char box[4] = {'[', 'X', ']', '\0'};
        }

        printf("%s", box);
        if (i == 3){
            j++;
            i = 0;
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

}
```